# Why does the delete button not get shown?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

```
<asp:DetailsView Width="750" runat="server" ID="ctlApplicationEdit" DefaultMode="Edit" DataSourceID="applicationDataSourceDetails" DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateRows="false" CssClass="EditApplicationWindow" OnModeChanged="OnApplicationChanged">
  <Fields>

<!-- Does not work as expected: (Delete button is not shown) -->

      <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" /> 

<!-- Works as expected: (Delete button is shown and calls the delete method when pressed)-->

      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
          <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Button ID="deleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"/>
          </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>

  </Fields>

</asp:DetailsView>
```

I have set up a `DeleteMethod` on the ObjectDataSource, and this is working as expected from the `TemplateField`.

My question is: Why does the command field only show Cancel and Update buttons, but not delete? Under what circumstances would this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to tell the DetailsView to auto generate the delete button.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.autogeneratedeletebutton(v=vs.110).aspx

`<asp:DetailsView AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True|False" />`

When the AutoGenerateDeleteButton property is set to true, a CommandField row field with a Delete button is automatically displayed in the DetailsView control. Clicking the Delete button permanently removes that record from the data source.